# javascript. Get the javascript function location or get function code

Tags: javascript, firebug, href

I have a deal with a 3rd party web page. And If I click on some of link, then a new "div"-window appears. This link element has the next code:

```
<a style="font-weight:600;font-size:15px;color:#7bb32e" href="javascript:openTag('code')" id="ext-gen1512">code</a>
```

**I need to get an openTag function code** in order to understand how it works.

In order to do this I use firebug. I tried make some approaches:
1) I tried to put "openTag" to command line of firebug and run it. But firebug tell that this function doesn`t exist (Reference error).

2)I tried to search the function name through all the files which were loaded with the page. But it was not success.

3) I created two html elements in my notepad and inserted them near that working thml element by using firebug. The code of these elements are:

```
1) <span onclick="openTag('mgmt')">mgmt 3</span>
2) <a href="javascript:openTag('mgmt')">mgmt 4</a>
```

When I click on the first span element, firefox console say that there is a reference error. Function openTag doesn`t exist.
But when I click on the second "a" element, it`s ok. There is no errors and the new "div"-window appears as it has to be.

**Please, help me to get openTag function code or figure out where this function is located.**

Comment: Can you provide us with the link for the page you are searching for this javascript function on.

Comment: @Mark Walters. Sorry, it is an intranet web page. There is no access from internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Firebug and switch to 'Script' panel. Reload the page if necessary.
2. Click 'Break on next' button (look for pause icon) on the top-left of Firebug.
3. Click your link. Unless there are event listeners for mouse events registered, the debugger will stop inside the code of your function.

Comment: I tried do it. But... While I was moving mouse pointer to the link, the div handler where link is located fired. And then 'Break on next' button turned off. And when i clicked on the link, 'Break on next' button did not catch any handlers. Does it exist hot key for the 'Break on next' button?

Comment: Yeah this can be annoying... I don't know any keyboard shortcut for this unfortunately.

Comment: What you can do is to open "Script" panel, focus Firebug's search, type your function name, and make sure "Multiple files" is selected.

Comment: Your "make sure \"Multiple files\" is selected" advice is very helpful. At list I found that function name in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The openTag() function must exist, either in an external js file or in the markup itself.  Try viewing the source of the original HTML page and go through the external js includes.

Comment: I tried to search in the markup page and external js files. But unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem. Here's how I solved it:

- Open Firebug Script tag, load all scripts
- In the right there's a 'New watch expression...' link (in the Watch tab)
- Click on that link and enter your function name
- Boom, directed me exactly to the source code for my function